# rviz doesn't show custom plugin

Tags: ros, rviz-plugins

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hey,

I created a plugin to show a mesh in rviz (basically an adaptation of the Polygon display). I had previously changed the source of the Polygon display to accept my message and display it as a mesh, this works fine. Then I wanted to export this plugin to my own package, however rviz doesn't seem to recognize it.

According to the tutorial, common problems are :

-Not having a plugin_description.xml (I have this located in the same package as the new plugin)

-Not exporting it in a package.xml file (I export it as follows:

```
<export>
    <rviz plugin="${prefix}/plugin_description.xml"/>
</export>
```

-Not properly referencing the library file from plugin_description.xml (I reference the path as

```
<library path="lib/librviz_plugin">
```

I reference the class as:

```
<class name="mesh_tools/Mesh" type="mesh::MeshDisplay" base_class_type="rviz::Display">
```

Which is inside the mesh_tools package. The class is called mesh::MeshDisplay and as is done for rviz::Polygon display, it has rviz::Display as base class. When I make everything, I do indeed get a devel/lib/librviz_plugin.so. The plugin_description.xml is not copied to the devel folder however. If I do catkin_make_isolated --install it will get copied, but rviz still can't see the display.

What can I do to debug this further? By the way, I am on Indigo with Ubuntu 14.04.

Best regards,
Hans

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/163476/rviz-doesn%27t-show-custom-plugin/) by [Hansg91](https://answers.ros.org/users/1621/hansg91/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1909 on 2014-05-10

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2014-07-24**:
What is the output of `rospack plugins --attrib=plugin rviz`?

**Comment by [Hansg91](https://answers.ros.org/users/1621/hansg91/) on 2014-08-01**:
Just the rviz plugins and the rviz tutorial, not my plugin.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2014-08-05**:
Ok, do you have a run & build depend in your manifest on rviz? For me, rospack only shows my pkg when querying for rviz plugins if I declare a dependency on the rviz pkg.

**Comment by [Hansg91](https://answers.ros.org/users/1621/hansg91/) on 2014-08-06**:
Aha, I wasn't aware I needed the run dependency on rviz, that was indeed the issue. If you add it as an answer, I can approve it. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Turns out the OP was missing a `run_depend` on package `rviz`, which caused the plugin not to show up (neither in RViz itself, nor in the output of `rospack plugins`).

---

> Aha, I wasn't aware I needed the run dependency on rviz, that was indeed the issue

I'd say it kind-of makes sense for a plugin for RViz to have a run dependency on it :)

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2014-08-06

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Hansg91](https://answers.ros.org/users/1621/hansg91/) on 2014-08-06**:
And it probably does make sense ;) oh well, lesson learned.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2014-08-19**:
As a final note: the requirement for the dependency on RViz is actually documented on the `pluginlib` [wiki page](http://wiki.ros.org/pluginlib#pluginlib.2BAC8-pluginlib_groovy.Registering_Plugin_with_ROS_Package_System):

> **Important Note**: In order for the above export command to work properly, the providing package must depend directly on the package containing the plugin interface.

**Comment by [Hansg91](https://answers.ros.org/users/1621/hansg91/) on 2014-08-19**:
Perhaps it is worth noting there that it should be a run dependency? I had a build_depend on rviz, but that didn't cut it.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2014-08-19**:
The page shows an example manifest, with both a run and build depend. So I think that is already covered. I just kept my quote small.